# How do I handle regular expression characters when doing a .match() on an exception using PyTest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test that looks like this:

```
@given(val=st.floats())
def test_validate_int_float(val):
    with pytest.raises(InvalidUsage) as ex:
        validate(val)
    print("{}|{}|{}".format(ex.value, f'Invalid value "{val}" for int param "n"',
                            ex.value == f'Invalid value "{val}" for int param "n"'))
    assert ex.match(f'Invalid value "{val}" for int param "n"')
```

When Hypothesis sets `val = 1e+16`, I get a failure.

```
E       AssertionError: Pattern 'Invalid value "1e+16" for int param "n"' not found in 'Invalid value "1e+16" for int param "n"'
```

The printed output for that failure is:

```
Invalid value "1e+16" for int param "n"|Invalid value "1e+16" for int param "n"|True
```

I believe this failure is happening because of the `+` character.

How do I properly match an exception message that contains a character used to define a regular expression? In thie case it failed on a `+`, but I have other tests that will use parenthesis, brackets, etc.

The [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest._code.ExceptionInfo.match) says that pytest is using `re.search()` behind the scenes in `.match()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But why are you using RE match when string equality works perfectly well?

```py
assert ex.value == f'Invalid value "{val}" for int param "n"'
```

If you really need to handle RE metacharacters, you can escape them beforehand:

```py
s = f'Invalid value "{val}" for int param "n"'
for ch in r"()[]{}.?*+^$|\":
    s = s.replace(ch, "\\" + ch)
assert ex.match(s)
```

Comment: What is the point of the `.match()` function in the Pytest library? Your suggestion works...if I wrap `ex.value` in `str()`. Otherwise, `ex.value` is an `ExceptionInfo` object (which has the `match() method) and it doesn't compare directly to a string.

Comment: I'd give you +1 for the suggestion of a simple string comparison but why did you propose that way of escaping characters in the second part of your answer instead of [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.escape)?